# Exporting values of unchecked items in Google Forms checklist

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Using Google Forms checkboxes to collect survey responses into a Sheets doc, I find that I can only get the values of checked lines to fill the spreadsheet.

I'm trying to get the unchecked CheckBox values to fill a different cell in the spreadsheet as well, has anyone found out a way to do this?

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have *a* way with spreadsheet formulas.

The drawbacks are the necessities of

- manual input of all possible options
- copying and pasting a formula for each response (can be done in advance, but if not enough formulas are pasted for the number of responses, the sheet will break)

An ideal solution would automatically detect all possible responses, and could theoretically accept an infinite number of responses without breaking and needing maintenance.

With that said, he's an example of what I suggest:

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C6a3ggLqLNNxyojQi2cZ4jBCQFFxZFRp8NcUNd64IZQ/edit#gid=1277333513)

[Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd9m7TiPUeVojjlfOOIQcsFL0k2JP_u6Dzi7AfuvgAOrKvm-Q/viewform)

All possible options on the form must be typed into cells `A2:A`

cells `B2:B` show comma+spaces if the corresponding cell in `A2:A` is not blank, with `=arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:A),"",", "))`. These commas and spaces are needed later in a `concatenate()`.

Raw data from the Form Responses spreadsheet was brought into `D2:E` with `=arrayformula('Form Responses 1'!A2:B)`

`G2:G` holds the important formulas. They must be copied and pasted to each individual cell for each row.

First, all possible responses in `$A$2:$B` are filtered based on if the cell in column A can be found in the text in column E.

```
=filter($A$2:$B,arrayformula(iserror(search($A$2:$A,E2))))
```

Next, some error catching. I added an `iferror()` to catch a "N/A, no results found in filter evaluation", and an `if(isblank(),"",)` to catch if no timestamp is in column D meaning no response was recorded in this row.

```
=if(isblank(D2),"",iferror(filter($A$2:$B,arrayformula(iserror(search($A$2:$A,E2)))),""))
```

Finally, do a `concatenate()` to pull the values and the comma+spaces all into one string inside one cell.

```
=concatenate(if(isblank(D2),"",iferror(filter($A$2:$B,arrayformula(iserror(search($A$2:$A,E2)))),"")))
```

Oh, and if you don't like the comma+space being the last characters in the string, in `J2:J` I did a `=arrayformula(iferror(left(H2:H,len(H2:H)-2),""))` which cuts off the last 2 characters of the string in column H.

If I come up with a better solution, I'll let you know. It's an interesting puzzle to solve.

Comment: Well-done! I figured I would need to do it manually but came up short on some of the syntax. This works perfectly for me thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue but mine is a form with Date and list of task that I need to complete everyday. And I'm trying to figure out a way to pull all the task that I missed.